# Cloning an object defined by inner class

Tags: java, clone, inner-classes, instance-variables

I have this vector that I am defining as an **instance variable** and also as an **inner class**:

```
private Vector<MATIdentifier> matIds = new Vector<MATIdentifier>(){

     @Override
    public boolean add(MATIdentifier mi){


     if(this.contains(mi)){

            return false;

          }
      super.add(mi);
      return true;

 }

   @Override
   public boolean contains(Object o){

         if(o instanceof MATIdentifier){


            for(MATIdentifier mi: this){

                if(mi.getIdValue().equals(((MATIdentifier)o).getIdValue())){

                 return true;

                }
           }
        }
                return false;

      }

};
```

Later on in the program, I want to populate this vector from the database. And it would be better to create a new instance of this Vector class, as opposed to simply removing all the elements and reusing the same object - I suppose I could do that, but I still want to know about cloning the object.

The only way I know how to do this would be to clone() this object. Is this safe? Will it clone the overridden methods add(MATIdentifier) and contains(Object) ?

Maybe I should override clone() also...? Or is the predefined clone() method in Vector sufficient?

Note: I put the @Override annotations in myself, the Java compiler (Eclipse) did not make me do that for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question deals with several concepts in Java.

Firstly, I'd like to ask why, if you want to guarantee uniqueness, you aren't using a [java.util.Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)?

Next, the clone method. Is the clone a [shallow copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy#Shallow_copy) or a [deep copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy#Deep_copy) of the original data structure? If we look at the [Vector API documentation from Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#clone%28%29), it tells us:

> Returns a clone of this vector. The copy will contain a reference to a
>   clone of the internal data array, not a reference to the original
>   internal data array of this Vector object.

So we can learn from this that, firstly, it also clones the internal data, so this suggests a deep copy. Now, does it also copy the overridden methods? A quick test of this tells me that, yes, it does.

Finally, how to test this? I suggest you use a unit testing framework like junit.
Following is an example of how to use this framework to ensure your assumptions are correct:

```
package test.good;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.Vector;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class CloneTest {

    private Vector<MATIdentifier> matIds;

    MATIdentifier id1 = new MATIdentifier("first");
    MATIdentifier id2 = new MATIdentifier("second");
    MATIdentifier id3 = new MATIdentifier("third");
    MATIdentifier idDuplicate = new MATIdentifier("first");

    @Before
    public void prepare() {
        matIds = new Vector<MATIdentifier>() {
            @Override
            public boolean add(MATIdentifier mi) {
                if (this.contains(mi)) {
                    return false;
                }
                super.add(mi);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean contains(Object o) {
                if (o instanceof MATIdentifier) {
                    for (MATIdentifier mi : this) {
                        if (mi.getIdValue().equals(((MATIdentifier) o).getIdValue())) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        };
    }

    private void populateVector(Vector<MATIdentifier> vector) {
        vector.add(id1);
        vector.add(id2);
        vector.add(id3);
    }

    /**
     * Tests that adding new values returns true, and adding duplicates returns
     * false, and that the duplicates are not actually added
     */
    @Test
    public void testDuplicateFails() {
        boolean added;
        added = matIds.add(id1);
        assertTrue(added);
        added = matIds.add(id2);
        assertTrue(added);
        added = matIds.add(idDuplicate);
        assertFalse(added);
        assertEquals(2, matIds.size());
    }

    @Test
    public void testDeepCopy() {
        // Start with by pupulating our customized vector
        populateVector(matIds);
        assertEquals(3, matIds.size());
        // Clone the vector
        Vector<MATIdentifier> clone = (Vector<MATIdentifier>) matIds.clone();
        assertEquals(3, clone.size());
        // remove something from the original
        matIds.remove(2);
        assertEquals(3, clone.size());
        assertEquals(2, matIds.size());
        // add something to the original
        matIds.add(new MATIdentifier("New Value"));
        assertEquals(3, clone.size());
        assertEquals(3, matIds.size());
        // add a duplicate to the clone, to ensure that the overridden behavior
        // is present in the clone
        boolean added = clone.add(id1);
        assertFalse(added);

    }

}

class MATIdentifier {
    private String idValue;

    public MATIdentifier(String idValue) {
        this.idValue = idValue;
    }

    public String getIdValue() {
        return idValue;
    }

    public void setIdValue(String idValue) {
        this.idValue = idValue;
    }

}
```

PS, it's probably better practice to either override the equals operation on MATIdentifier or to create a MATIdentifier [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) than to create a custom contains and add impl for your Vector. I'd really suggest you use a java.util.Set.
Also, creating anonymous inner types like this with what I assume is important functionality is not a good practice, as it makes your code more difficult to test. If you insist on continuing with a specialized Vector implementation, you should move it into a class.

Comment: as opposed to using Java Set, this way I believe I will know if the user (or me the programmer) tried to check to see if the Vector contained a type that was not MATIdentifier. I could put a print or logging statement in the contains method if the type is not MATIdentifier.

Comment: also, as you said, I would have to at least override equals(Object) in java.util.Set. I am guessing overriding equals in Set will give Set the contains functionality that is desired - as is desired above in my Vector subclass. So I would have to put my Set subclass in a different class also, or as an inner class, right?

Comment: also note this: http://smallwig.blogspot.com/2007/12/why-does-setcontains-take-object-not-e.html

Comment: It's weird that the clone contains overridden methods although this behaviour is never mentioned in the oracle definition of either clone or clonable.